# Pass response to the 2nd `then` of a $q promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

Take a look at this simple example:

```
function colorPromise() {
  return $q.when({data:['blue', 'green']})
}

function getColors() {
  return colorPromise().then(function(res) {
     console.log('getColors', res)
     // do something with res
  };
}

function testGetColors() {
  getColors().then(function(res) {
    if (angular.equals(res, {data:['blue', 'green']})) {
      console.log('passes')
    }
  });
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LHgTeL9sDs7jyoS7MJTq?p=preview
In this example `res` in the `testGetColors` function is `undefined`.

**How can you pass `res` to the second `then` function in `$q` promise?**

Comment: What is `res` and where does it come from?

Comment: @jfriend00 this is `res`: ` return $q.when({data:['blue', 'green']})`

Comment: a side note ... `getColors.then` should be `getColors().then` ... surely this is a typo in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning it in your first `then`.:

```
function getColors() {
  return colorPromise().then(function(res) {
     console.log('getColors', res)
     // do something with res

     return res; //<---
  };
}
```

`.then` returns a promise itself. If the `function` you passed to it returned a non-promise value, that promise will immediately be resolved with that return value (this is what happens in your case, as your function returned `undefined` (nothing)). Note that you can also return a promise in your `then`-function, to make the `then`-promise become that promise.

Answer (score 5):

You need to return `res`

```
function getColors() {
  return colorPromise().then(function(res) {
     console.log('getColors', res)
     return res; // here
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a `return res` in your `getColors` function, see [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zdG3iXIhIM8goD9x1Gdf?p=preview)